# SQL statement with where clause subquery to DAX expression

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery

I have a query written in SQL that I want to convert to DAX.

```
SELECT DISTINCT TeamId
FROM Teams 
WHERE UId NOT IN
    (
        SELECT UId
        FROM Items 
    )
 AND IsArchived = 0
```

The power bi data model relationship with Teams and Items is One-to-Many (Teams to Items).
How can I convert the above SQL to DAX.

Comment: Are you looking for a new DAX table of unique team id's or a measure that counts the number of teams matching the criteria?

Comment: I'm looking for a new DAX table with unique team id where the ID in teams table is not in Items

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution to the task.

```
SELECT DISTINCT TeamId
FROM Teams 
WHERE TeamId NOT IN
    (
        SELECT TeamId
        FROM Items 
    )
 AND IsArchived = 0
```

I used EXCEPT function in DAX.

```
EXCEPT(VALUES('Teams'[TeamId]), VALUES(DriveItems[TeamId]))
```

This returns distinct TeamID as a table